# Python feedparser's bozo is of bool type instead of int

Tags: python, integer, boolean, feedparser

Disclaimer first: I am a python newbie.

I am using `feedparser` version 6.0.8 (checked using `pip freeze | grep feedparser`) to parse Twitter feeds from random Nitter instances (using twiiit.com). Python version is 3.9.2 on Linux MX. The problem is that according to docs (https://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/reference-bozo.html) the variable responsible for indicating whether a parsed rss is a well-formated XML is of integer type but in my case it is (almost) always a bool. What is even more troubling is that when bozo is of bool type it does not indicate if a parsed feed is an xml correctly.

At first I have thought that it has something to do with implicit int to bool conversion (0 -> false and 1 -> true) but it is not. Most of the time the result is a bool of value false and it is a valid feed (at least thunderbird can parse it correctly). However it is not a rule because sometimes it is false-bozo and thunderbird cannot parse it*.

Mnimal working example:

```
import requests
import feedparser


url = 'http://twiiit.com/nws/rss'
print("Requesting rss feed for:"+url)
resp = requests.get(url)
rss_content = resp.content
d=feedparser.parse(rss_content)
print('bozo value:',d.bozo)
if type(d.bozo) is int:
    print('bozo as int')
elif type(d.bozo) is bool:
    print('bozo as bool')
else :
    print('bozo is of unknown type')
```

What I expect is something like

```
bozo value:0
bozo as int
```

but instead I have this:

```
bozo value: False
bozo as bool
```

*it is a simplification, in order for thunderbird to update feeds I need to modify them so that ids from different Nitter instances are the same if they refer to the same tweet.

Comment: convert the bool to an int  `bozo=1 if bozo else 0`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki So it is a valid behavior? I mean implicit conversion.

Comment: You are getting a bool and want an int, so just convert the bool to an int. What you mean if it's valid behavior?

Comment: Why the docs says about int type when in fact the library is using bool?